# exiting while loop algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

what is the algorithm for a while loop invariant?
for example,

```
while(object.width()<=15 && object.color()!=blue || object.material==green)
    buyObject(object)
```

What are the conditions under which one wouldn't buyObject?

Comment: Keep in mind that && has higher precedence, i.e. that the condition is `(object.width() <= 15 && object.color() != blue) || object.material == green` (I took the liberty of adding some spaces) and think about it for a moment. It's really not that hard.

Comment: object.width =16 && object.color = blue

Comment: One wouldn't `buyObject` when the `while` expression is false.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Actually, that should be OR object.color=blue, not AND.

Comment: I would argue that this is defective code, and that the programmer should add parenthesis so that nobody has to ask a question like this in the first place.

Comment: @CPerkins -- Who's to say he intended to give a *correct* answer?

Comment: What seems to be a problem here?

Comment: The problem is that someone keeps deleting my comments.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will go on until the expression in the `while` is false.
The condition is this expression :
`object.width() <= 15 && object.color() != blue || object.material==green`

For that expression to be false, it needs both conditions of the OR ( `||` ) to be false, which are :

`object.width() <= 15 && object.color() != blue`

and

`object.material==green` .

For the second one to be false, it's clear what is needed.
For the first one, one of the two conditions that are checked with AND ( `&&` ) needs to be false, which are :

`object.width() <= 15`

and

`object.color() != blue` .

From here, finding which conditions will make the loop stops should be easy.

Comment: If I use (object.width>15 || object.color()==blue && object.material!=green) as the false condition, what kind of parenthesis are necessary?

Comment: Check the comment to your question made by Sebastian Redl, that should give you the answer.

Comment: so because the default is precedence of &&, I should put brackets around the first condition, i.e. (   (object.width>15 || object.color()==blue)   &&object.material==green)